# How do I sort nodes by it's Argument?

Tags: python, networkx

I'll write an example to clarify what I mean:

```
test = nx.Graph()
test.add_edge(0,3)
test.add_edge(1,2)
test.nodes 
Out: NodeView((0, 3, 1, 2))
nx.to_numpy_matrix(test)
Out: matrix([[0., 1., 0., 0.],
            [1., 0., 0., 0.],
            [0., 0., 0., 1.],
            [0., 0., 1., 0.]])
```

So if you check the example above you can see that networkx orders the nodes in the order that you add them to the graph.

The problem is that I need my adjacency matrix to be ordered by the number given to the node. So for my example, the final matrix has to be:

```
Out: matrix([[0., 0., 0., 1.],
            [0., 0., 1., 0.],
            [0., 1., 0., 0.],
            [1., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Moreover, I'm reading the graph from a file that is an edge list.

At the end my **real problem** is that the indices of the out matrix differ from the ones in the graph. So for my example if I want to check the node 1 in the matrix I have to write matrix[2] as it's the third node i write in the edge list.
Does anybody know how could I fix this?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what do u mean with 'backworks'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know your nodes in advance then you could add them to the graph before adding edges. For example,

```
>>> G = nx.Graph()
>>> G.add_node(0)
>>> G.add_node(1)
>>> G.add_node(2)
>>> G.add_node(3)
>>> G.add_edge(0,3)
>>> G.add_edge(1,2)
>>> G.nodes
NodeView((0, 1, 2, 3))
>>> nx.to_numpy_matrix(G)
matrix([[0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Or, looking at the API docs, you could simply do,

`print(nx.to_numpy_matrix(test, nodelist=[0,1,2,3]))`

Output:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: The problem is that I read it from a file, as I said, so I can't really do that or at least I don't know how.

Comment: I see. Wouldn't a linear scan of your file give you the max number of nodes in your graph? I guess you are trying to avoid that.

Comment: I actually now the number of nodes the network has but still, using the nx.read_edge_list() would creating the network in the order of the edge list given.

Comment: @aarcas Updated my answer

Comment: `nx.to_numpy_matrix(test, nodelist=sorted(test.nodes))`  good solution +1  Nice find look at the API.

Comment: Yes! Didn't think about that but it should work, thanks.